# How do I run sqlline with Phoenix?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, squirrel-sql, apache-phoenix

When I try to run Phoenix's `sqlline.py localhost`command, I get

```
WARN util.DynamicClassLoader: Failed to identify the fs of 
dir hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase/lib, ignored
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme:
hdfs at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass...
```

and nothing else happens. I also could not get Squirrel to work (it freezes when I click 'list drivers').

As per [these](http://phoenix.apache.org/download.html#Installation) instructions, I have copied phoenix-4.2.1-server.jar to my hbase/lib folder and restarted hbase. I have also copied core-site.xml and hbase-site.xml to my phoenix/bin directory.

I have not added `'the phoenix-[version]-client.jar to the classpath of any Phoenix client'`
since I do not know what this refers to.

I am using HBase 0.98.6.1-hadoop2, Phoenix 4.2.1 and hadoop 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I fix the same issue by adding setting in
**${PHOENIX_HOME}/bin/hbase-site.xml**

```
<property>  
        <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>  
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>  
</property>
```